# Array/List/Vector type which fills intermediate values in C++?

Tags: c++

I read about the vector/list/map types contained in the stardard template library of C++ and I couldn't find one that behaved as such:

```c++
myMap::autofillingmap m;
m[0] = 2; // m[] = [2]
m[1] = 3; // m[] = [2, 3]
m[4] = 5; // m[] = [2, 3, 0, 0, 5]
m[10] = 1 // m[] = [2, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Is there any cpp lib that emulates this behavior?

(**beforehand observation**: *Yes, I do know this is not optimal methodology to work data structures out. Thanks)*

Comment: Re: _"This is similar behavior to lists' natural bevahior in python, but nulls would be placed instead of 0s."_ Are you sure you're thinking of the right language? Python lists don't permit out-of-bounds assignments. Writing something like `l = []; l[10] = 1` would raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: You can simulate with `std::array` or `std::vector`. Simply declare and initialize all 11 elements `0` and then assign values to the indexes needed. See [C++ Containers library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: sorry I was wrong about python. Took out that part

Comment: Seems like you would be better off with a sparse vector. Both boost and Eigen suppor tthis. Here is boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.html

Comment: You can call resize on a std::Vector.  So, for example,  `v.resize(x+1); v[x] = y;` would work.

Comment: You can _use_ vector like that if you want.  Just with a free (template) function, not a method.  In other words, define a template function `void store<T>(std::vector& v, size_t index, T value)` and make it do `resize(index+1); v[index] = value`.  Use it consistently.  Done.  (I see @JerryJeremiah got there slightly first.  My contribution is: Just because there isn't a _built-in_ method for it in some class don't let _that_ stop you. C++ has functions too - as well as all kinds of other stuff.)

Comment: You can emulate fairly simple by inheriting from std::vector, e.g.,  https://godbolt.org/z/Po56ffxjK

Comment: @benroberts999 yes it's easy to do, but for the love of God don't do it.  I had to work with a codebase that had an auto resizing vector like that, and I hated it.

Comment: I think that in this case it would be useful to create a **class** for an ```Abstract Data Type``` or **ADT** ```myMap``` that can use operators such as ```[], =, []=, <<``` etc ...

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure..but it's a completely new class, not std::vector, so doesn't change existing code, and no one is forced to use it. You may hate an auto re-sizing container, but it's exactly what OP wants

Comment: @benroberts999 in my case I *was* forced to use it, because they integrated other stuff as member functions instead of using free-standing functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote `myMap` **struct** which use a `std::vector<int>` to store values, `myMap` I also have tried a basic `Insert()` method that interpret your example to assign values.

```
struct myMap {
        vector<int> _data;
        size_t _capacity;
        myMap(size_t capacity);
        const myMap& operator=(const myMap&);
        int operator [] (int index);
        void Insert(int idx, int value);
};

myMap::myMap(size_t capacity) : _capacity(capacity) {
    _data.resize(capacity);
}

const myMap& myMap::operator=(const myMap& rhs){

    _data = rhs._data;;
    return *this;
}

int myMap::operator[](int idx) {
    return _data[idx];
}

void myMap::Insert(int idx, int value) {

    if (idx >= _data.size())     
        _data.resize(idx+1);      

    _data[idx] = value;
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YGxWa4TGr)